# Energy of states in non-equilibrium systems

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, research-level

In equilibrium thermodynamics, the Boltzmann distribution gives the probability of finding a system in a certain $i$: $P_i = e^{-\frac{E_i}{k_B T}}$. Conversely, by measuring state probabilities one could derive the energy of the state $E_i = - k_B T \log{P_i}$.

For an out-of-equilibrium system, the states do not follow a Boltzmann distribution anymore. However, in some cases we can still define state probability - stochastic systems based on Master equations and Fokker-Planck equations for example.

Now we could think about defining energy from probability distributions obtained in this way. So for instance, suppose we have a time-dependent solution to a Master equation $\{P_i(t)\}_{i=1}^{N}$. Then we could define an energy (in units of $k_B T$) which is time-dependent: $E_i(t) \equiv -\log{P_i(t)}$.

Now I wonder whether such a definition has any meaning and useful implications. For instance, would the total energy decrease, increase or stay constant over time?

**EDIT**

In fact, we could define the total energy as $E(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} E_i(t) P_i(t) = - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} P_i(t) \log{P_i(t)}$, which is the same as the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))! Still, I wonder whether $E_i(t) \equiv -\log{P_i(t)}$ has any interpretation. Also, can we prove that this entropy increases over time for any out-of-equilibrium system?

Comment: Your $E$ is actually the *free* energy which does appear in non-equilibrium thermodynamics. See [Jarzynski equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarzynski_equality)

Comment: Why so? It looks more like an internal energy to me and at the same time it looks the same as the Shannon entropy. Or does the sum over the states determine whether it's a $free$ energy?

Comment: If you include the partition function into the probability, $P_i=Z^{-1}\exp(-E_i/k_BT)$, then, taking into account $Z=\exp(-F/k_BT)$, you will find that $E=F+TS$ ($F$ is the free energy, $S$ in the entropy).